# Python 2.7 int(str, base) confusion

Tags: python-2.7, radix

I am trying to use the int(x,  base) class functionality using Python 2.7

when I do:
`num = int('100', 2)` 
I receive the answer 4

however, when I do `num = int('72', 2)` I get the following traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foobar1.py", line 26, in <module>
    num = int('72', 4)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 4: '72'
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: What did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base number is specifying the numeric base of the value. For example, setting base to 16 means you are working with a hexadecimal number, while setting it to 8 means you are working with numbers in octal.

In octal (base 8), the digits available to you are 0--7. Trying to convert the number '89' using the function num = int('89', 8) will give you an error because the digits 8 and 9 are not used in base 8 numbers. Similarly, in base 2, the only digits available to you are 0 and 1 - the highest digit allowed will be the base number - 1.

Hopefully this clears things up.

Comment: thank  you, that is exactly the information I needed.  I guess I wasn't actually clear on what the functionality was doing.

Answer (score 1):

`72` is not a binary number (at a minimum it's base 8), but when you specify a base of `2`, you assert that it is. So your function fails.

```
num = int('1001000', 2)
```

or:

```
num = int('1020', 4)
```

would work as expected, for instance, and give you an integer that will be equivalent to decimal `72`.

Answer (score 1):

Second parameter means base. Base 2 means the number can use only 2 numbers (which are 0 and 1). When you are trying to convert 72 from binary (base 2) it fails because numbers 7 and 2 do not exist in binary.

If you are trying to convert your number **to** binary, use [bin()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin)